# docker container already started, but starting the service in intellij cannot find the started node

Tags: docker, corda, activemq-artemis

Can anyone help me with my issue, I was able to start the nodes using docker, but when I tried to start my service/web-service it cannot find the nodes that is already started in container.

error says

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'nodeRPCConnection': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is
>   ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException[errorType=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT
>   message=AMQ119013: Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology.
>   Group:null]

for the docker ps -a
this is the results 
[docker result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rB9yT.png)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what your node configurations are but this mostly happens when the node is not reachable from the client. This could happen because of incorrect RPC configurations (host/ port incorrectly configured).

Make sure you have the correct host and port configured for your node.

Also if you are using the official Docker image, it exposes `10200`, `10201` and `10202` ports for `p2p`, `rpc` and `rpcAdmin` ports respectively.

Take a look at this blog for reference:

https://medium.com/corda/containerising-corda-with-corda-docker-image-and-docker-compose-af32d3e8746c

Also, this video demos how to get started with Corda on Docker:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ITMOiMzkX4I&t=2s